# Как лучше хранить сообщения пользователей телеграм бота?

Tags: база-данных, sqlite, aiogram

Сейчас есть sqlite БД с таблицей зарегистрированных в боте пользователей и таблицей сообщений всех пользователей, но чувствую такую модель не оптимальной. Как лучше оптимизировать модель БД?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: | id_user | message_user | - что может быть лучше? можно ещё | date_message | для поиска сообщений по дате.